# Make Gradle to forget Proxy

Tags: android-studio, gradle, proxy, tor

I've set tor proxy for android studio. As Gradle just uses HTTP/HTTPS proxies and can not pass through tor's socks network, now I removed the proxy from Android Studio's settings, but Gradle still uses socks network and faces error:

```
Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: Tor is not an HTTP Proxy
```

How can I remove proxy also from Gradle's settings?

Answer (score 0):

There are two files named gradle.properties:

- One in the project's root, and
- another in $HOME/.gradle, which is probably ~/.gradle in Linux and C:\Users\<user>\.gradle in Windows.

Make sure that proxy settings are removed from both.